How can dragons breathe in space?
So, I'm writing about a world consisting of 15+ planets, which revolve around a giant star in the middle of the universe. My question is how I can create a realistic, logical way for dragons to cross the space between planets. (This is a world with very little technology.)

Are you asking about surviving in space or traveling between worlds? Can you please [edit] your post to clarify and add details about how dragons work in your world.

Please allow me to make an important point... you have an imaginary world wherein dragons exist and can fly in space... and you want a "realistic" answer. We love helping people rationalize their imaginary worlds and frankly, the crazier the better! We love the challenge! But please set your expectations. @SurpriseDog has given you what is likely the one and only "realistic" answer to this question. (Good thing you didn't ask how they could "fly.") Having said that, if you could use any words to describe your question other than realistic, plausible, or feasible, what would they be?

Breathing is the biological process of expelling carbon dioxide and bringing in oxygen. There isn't a lot of CO2 or O2 in outer space. So breathing would be pointless. Holding your breath would also be pointless since there are open holes in almost any animal's body. A better way to rephrase your question is "How can a naked organism travel through space without suffocating?" And to answer to that is they must not require Oxygen to begin with.

In one volume of Anne McCaffery's Dragonriders of Pern series, she has the dragons use their ability to teleport to go into space. They were evidently able to hold their breath for quite a while. No explanation of how they were able to function in a vacuum, but it didn't appear to effect them at all. No eye protection, etc. ??

Awh, what a vacuous question. Not that I mean it, yet s/one had to make this comment.

Are there any "aliens" who can leave ships/teleports/wormholes behind?

What's that sci fi book where the atmosphere slightly connects now and again - it's named something like "the spaceships of wood" or "the starships with sails" - surely someone here remembers!

the one sci-fi universe in which biological creatures travel through space that I can think of right now is Farscape. I don't remember if energy generation specifically is mentioned, but I would assume that, instead of relying on oxydation for energy, they rely on light instead.

Whales can hold their breath for a very long time while diving.  Perhaps something similar?

Points system bit me again, so commenting here against convention. Sorry, but not that sorry. Anyhoo, some lore of dragons speculate the 'breath weapon' of dragons comes from a set of glands that secrete a material that becomes hypergolic when mixed. Perhaps one of them as an oxidizer can be utilized as an O2 source. Also, suppose the wing scales interact with the magnetosphere of the planet for propulsion. Planet to planet they have to time the jump right, but near a planet they push against the magnetic fields (there are real propulsion system like this). Between planets, hibernate.

They hold their breath
On Earth, salt-water crocodiles can hold their breath for up to an hour underwater. An impressive feat, but no where near as impressive as the magical dragons in your world who flap their wings to achieve escape velocity and then cruise between worlds in a special catatonic state holding their breath for days or even weeks at a time.

+1 for the special catatonic state.

There is a very memetic scene from Invincible that comes to mind.

not to mention their superb instinctive understanding of orbital mechanics, which allows them to plot a precise course between planets, without needing any correction burns and without missing their target and drifting off into the void forever.

I had come to say the same, inspired by Invincible (BTW, @The Square-Cube Law, you did a lot of damage – I have read the wholl Invincible, now I also want to see the animated series :D )

Here's a much larger issue about dragons crossing the vacuum of space: if they try and reach escape velocity from the ground, which they have to do because the only propulsion they have (wings) requires an atmosphere, they would be vaporized by air particles hitting them at hypersonic velocities and arrive at their destination as dust. As much as making your world realistic can help, sometimes it's not what you really want, and will end up with a lot of things turning to ash/asphyxiating in space/freezing to death/causing vacuum decay from the infinite-energy-producing magic particle...
My suggestion? They're not "planets", they're all smaller planetoids that are magically suspended very close to one another around a very dim star, so that their upper atmospheres intersect. Increase the atmosphere height by enough that they can be separated far enough so that they still look like our planets do in the night sky (sort of - might be closer to how the Moon looks in the sky) and there you go. A dragon doesn't have to reach escape velocity to travel between planets; they can just go up high enough that they functionally reach "space", just a region of very low air pressure so that it's hard to fly/breathe but still possible, and then fall back to another world. Sort of like how Terraria's Calamity mod justified finding big planetoids just above the atmosphere that you could reach without choking to death: they're magically suspended in a very low orbit due to a long-past cataclysm.
This adds a neat little detail that younger dragons would probably have much difficulty travelling between "planets" without help, because the lung and wing power required to do so would probably necessitate being at least adolescent, or at least adult, or at least 150,000 years old, or what have you.
Of course this isn't a realistic answer - your world is completely unrealistic. There are plenty of reasons dragons can't exist on any habitable planet for long, and no organism that evolved on the ground would ever have a reason to build super-lungs capable of holding breaths for month- or year-long interplanetary journeys, let alone scales strong enough to withstand reentry ablation or wings powerful enough to get to escape velocity. If you're looking for realism, then you'll have to design a highly-intelligent draconic society capable of building high-efficiency engines and other parts, refine large amounts of quality fuel, assemble large structures like interplanetary rockets, and design botanical systems that can keep a dragon alive for months or years on end. And then you have to make it feasible for the society to spend the equivalent of billions of US dollars on building one of these ships just so that one dragon can go visit her mom or burn down a village or whatever.
Best I can do given your explicitly-stated low tech level is magic. It would be just as simple to do interplanetary portals, given that dragons' existence already violates a few rules of nature.

Terry Pratchett came up with an obvious-in-hindsight solution to the wings issue: a creature that breathes fire is more-or-less a rocket.

@aantia boggle   my immediate mental picture of a dragon is fire breathing-out-the-mouth.   So would these dragons be like rockets that fly though in reverse, tail first?   Or do they make like a human who ate a spicy chilli and breathe fire at the other end ?   I'm tempted to post as a new question.

If a creature can breathe fire, then by definition they have the capacity to store and ignite fuel as well as expel the ignition's products as propellant in a controlled way. A dragon, with wings, is also aerodynamic enough that it can control its accelerated flight through an atmosphere effectively. These are also properties of a rocket.

@Criggie The latter, rather unfortunately! See Guards, Guards! and The Last Hero for details (or the wiki entry)

Surely if dragons can do all they do, they could make a PLASMA (!!!) or something "shield" around themselves, for exit-reentry ???

@aantia seeing as pratchett's dragons flew backwards... was the word 'hindsight' a deliberate choice?

@Fattie Keep in mind that reentry plasma is precisely what heat shields are intended to prevent from reaching the extremely-fragile command pod and occupants of human spacecraft. Making a heat shield out of that plasma seems a bit counterproductive.

@controlgroup for sure!  I was using "PLASMA" in the sci-fi sense of "mysterious Energy Shield Beyond Normal Science". :)

In that case it makes perfect sense ;)

Or they could be large moons orbiting a gas giant.

Even better. There I would say it would have to be a lot of tight orbits, but it could work.

A universe full of sky
Let's start with the obvious. You have dragons already, so why not bend the rules a bit further? And with a bit I mean a whole lot.
Realistically a dragon can't fly from planet to planet. Imagine a dragon flying around the planet in a single flight, no stops for food or anything. Then do it another 8,5 times. That is just the distance to the moon. If we do the same for Mercury, the on average closest planet to Earth, we see that they need to fly slightly less than 2000 times around the Earth for that distance.
That means that breathing won't make a difference. They will be long dead from water, then food, then exhaustion before they even get close to any planet.
To make it all bearable, we make the planets behave and get close to each other. Then we fill the universe with air. Anything on a stellar scale will continue as normal. The sunrays reach the planets as if through a vacuum. The planets are in a fixed orbit that allows for the dragons to fly from one to another. Or mayby only at times the orbits get close enough.
The air between the planets is traversable by flying. They simply fly through the not so thin air, gliding towards the next planet at terminal velocity when getting close enough.

Gravity will have to follow very different laws. Filling a volume with gas means it will just compress into spheres of super-compressed gas, probably igniting fusion. If you assume gravity is instantaneous, you can't even calculate the effect an infinity of matter unless it is perfectly evenly distributed. I still love the suggestions, but I'd really suggest trying to to make it realistic, or even explain anything, as you'll inevitably end in physical impossibilities and redesigning such a universe with a "minimum set of changes" to standard physics will have to change almost everything.

@toolforger we're already ignoring things like heating from the planets moving through the universe full of air, gravity between the planets, light reaching them.... at this point put it on the tab. Dragons will never reach any planet without massive changes. That being said, why not? No one clucks at the large animals surviving years of winter in the world of A song of ice and fire. You just accept it, as that is how the story goes.

I'm just saying that you have to do more than must make the planetary orbits smaller, you have to away with the entire concept of gravity as in the Kepler/Newton setup. In particular, there's no formula for gravity that has both stable orbits and equidistributed matter, so you need something different than gravity to keep the planets on their orbits.

there is a sci-fi book like this, about two planets - can't recall the name

They have a dormant hibernation state
Like tardigrades they can shift into a hibernation mode where their DNA is protected and they dehydrate and curl up into a ball. They'll reach space, accelerate for a while and take some damage, and then curl up and wait for arrival several months or years later. They probably secrete a protective layer to help re-entry and minimize damage from cosmic rays.
They would of course need to be quite tough and efficient to survive space for a little time.
They have a photosynthetic mode
As well as hibernating, they can extend their wings to drink up sunlight. If doing a long journey they'll land on an asteroid or meteorite and drink up lots of water and carbon dioxide and then use sunlight to convert it into sugar and oxygen.

Portals
One of my favorite novel series is a steampunk/fantasy trilogy called His Dark Materials.
In this work, the Aurora Borealis (northern lights) are actually portals that connect different universes. When you look at them up close you can see cities and other features on different planes of existence, each with their own rules. Witches know about these, angels supposedly use these and other means to travel between worlds and a scientist in the story successfully creates a mini-aurora at ground level and uses it to travel to another dimension.
Now look at my username. You have dragons, which are probably very heavy and would need kilometer-wide wings to fly, yet you have them fly anyway. You are in violation of me already, the only thing keeping your dragons from collapsing under their own weight or dying of asphyxia is magic. Add a little more magic and make it so that they can open up portals to other worlds.
Make it so that they can only open it from high up in the atmosphere if you want to add an extra dramatic effect to it.

How do you open a portal without creating a huge pressure differential? Do it in a vacuum. Makes sense to me. +1

Dragons are cold-blooded. Very cold. So cold, in fact, that in place of lungs they have internal tanks of liquid oxygen and hydrogen (or methane or whatever, take your pick). This is how they are able to breathe such large amounts of fire on such short notice - it's literally rocket exhaust.
You can tell when a dragon is about to fly interplanetary because it flies backwards, as fast and as high as it can, right up into the upper atmosphere, before igniting its fiery breath and burning, wings furled, legs tucked, tail stretched out in front, until it reaches orbital velocity.
After that they travel much as any other spacecraft would, burning just the right amounts of breath at just the right moments to reach their destination with the minimum of delta-v. If you want to write about this realistically, you should spend some time playing Kerbal Space Program.
An interplanetary dragon spends months or years in space, as any realistic spacecraft must. But this is ok - dragons don't use much energy when they're not active, because they're so very cold-blooded. The little oxygen they do need is no problem - it's right their in liquid form in their internal tanks.

They breathe the aether
As it turns out, the Michelson-Morley experiment was wrong. There is an aether field that connects the whole universe and dragons use this aether to

Navigate
Breathe
Feed

Being magical creatures, dragons interact with the aether field and can thus propel themselves and navigate by flapping their wings as if it was air. The aether also nourishes the magical dimension of their lungs/stomach, so that they endure the long passage between planets.

If the aether is much (much much) more dense than the atmosphere, this also explains the ability of their comparatively-tiny wings to lift their enormous weight despite being about a kilometer too short.

They are truly incredibly heavy
To breathe in space, dragons need an atmosphere. This means they possess an incredibly high density and gravitational field, forming an atmospheric layer around them even in space.
When these dragons leave a planet, they take part of the atmosphere with them and provide the remaining atmosphere when they arrive at another planet. While traveling through space, they draw their long necks toward the center of gravity to breathe efficiently. After gas exchange, the dragons then expel the air at a speed exceeding the escape velocity.

Such a dragon, when landing, would immediately attract any loose debris. Including soil, stones, rocks, probably break apart sedimentary rock, and immediately become a super-dense mound on Earth, unable to ever take off again unless it is strong enough to lift its own super-mass and all the accreted mass.

what a great idea !

Internal Combustion
So everyone knows that dragons breathe fire. But have you ever wondered where that fire comes from? Of course not - it's magic! Every dragon just has the power of fire within their very bodies.
It makes sense, then, that such a magical creature might adapt this power for biological processes. Breathing is for things like humans or rabbits. Dragons don't need to breathe - instead, they sustain themselves on this magical internal fire.
The existence of this fire is also a great way to figure about how a dragon might achieve such propulsion to begin with, both to lift off away from a planet and to navigate through space (since flapping wings does nothing without air). After all, bringing along combustible fuels is the main way modern humans achieve this in their spacecraft.
Or just handwave it all away
You're already in a world where you have dragons, they can fly, they can get into space, and they can get to other planets reasonably quickly. Why not just hand-wave away the breathing problem as well? That's part of the fun with fantasy stories: don't focus on how the impossible is possible, but focus on the implications of this new, unreal world.

If you want to get a bit mores sciencey, the dragon's breath also includes oxidizer and that's how it gets so famously hot. In space, the breath-gland instead converts the stored oxidizer back into oxygen.

They use "Greater teleport".
Seriously, you have a world with dragons. The most realistic way of dragons travelling to other planets is magic. If you try to provide a scientific explanation to why your dragons can fly to other planets you will shatter the suspension of disbelief of your intended target far more easily than just saying 'magic'. Any attempt to provide some technobabble to justify dragon interplanetary travel will leave more questions than answers - how do they fly at all, how do they achieve escape velocity, how do they survive the travel, how do they make orbital corrections, how do they survive re-entry, etc, etc...

+1 a dragon flying through interplanetary space is as realistic as one flying through air.

Spitballing here.

Dragons could have extra-dimensional breathing apparatus.

Dragons use interior portals to draw air from another place.

Dragons don't "breathe". They consume energy from particles. They produce fire and energy from atomic combustion or harnessing the movement of electrons. Since it is void, they bring a certain quantity of atoms that they gradually break down for energy.



Mass-energy converting food rather than digesting it chemically would indeed be many orders of magnitude more efficient...

I have to believe the best solution is:
They form a "shield" or "energy field diver's suit" around themselves ...
This solves ALL PROBLEMS.

Your dragons MUST have some sort of SHIELD against entry/reentry, just as the space shuttle had those tiles. You MUST have this or it makes no sense.

A great plot point is that - imagine this "suit" is, say, a meter or so bigger than the dragon all around - then, they have only that much air before reaching the target planet. It intros more complications, they have to make it in time, they can become stranded etc.


Enjoy!

They can Survive Cryostasis
Unlike Mammals, many species of reptiles can completely freeze for an indefinite period of time.  While frozen their metabolism completely stops meaning they don't need to breath or eat at all until they warm back up.  So, as long as there is some manner of heat shield between them and the sun, they will freeze until they re-enter another atmosphere. If their wings have an adequately reflective coating they could cocoon themselves with thier wings to let thier bodies cool to freezing.  This would allow them to spend months (or even centuries if they accidentally miss) adrift in space without dying.
... and thier Dragon Breath is a "natural" Rocket Engine
The hard part will be escape velocity.  In theory, they could use thier wings to get up to a certain altitude ... but planets run out of air a lot faster than they run out of gravity.  This is where dragon breath comes into play.  After all, what is dragon fire if not a rocket engine that is sometimes used to burn up greedy adventurers?
Granted, this would not work by any currently achieved form of chemistry because they would have to expend no less than 80% of thier body mass just to get out to space, but there are many ways you could chose to handwave a more efficient fuel that is unique to dragons. The most scientifically plausible explanation would be metallic hydrogen.  If they gorge themselves in preparation for a flight thier bodies could reasonably store a mass of 25% metallic hydrogen which would be enough fuel to escape a 1g planet.  A slightly less realistic, but plausible explanation would be that thier fire breath is actually nuclear powered, in which case, maybe they eat rocks rich in uranium which would barely take any added body mass at all (assuming you're okay with dragons that have Godzilla level "fire" breath).  But your best bet is to just call it magic.  If your setting has dragons, you've already set foot into a fantasy setting; so, you might as well run with it.  If these dragons are part of an actual Sci-fi setting, then just handwave it as Clarke tech: "IE: The explorers were baffled by how the dragons bodies can produce so much power, it's like nothing they had ever seen before."

Frame challenge
"a realistic, logical way for dragons to cross the space between planets"
Cannot be done.

Flying dragons wouldn't have lift in vacuum, so you'd need for them to be either equipped with a very powerful reaction drive (insert joke here), or be able to teleport. If you also make them telepathic and bonded to a dragonrider, Anne McCaffrey isn't going to be amused.
In microgravity you can't fly anyway (you have to swim in the air, a totally different skill), and there is no pressure to keep the dragon's blood from boiling, some seconds before the nitrogen outbubbling has given your dragon a fatal case of the bends.
Reentry on the target planet would likely see the dragon go down (or up, depending on the point of view) in flames. Unless you had very small planets. But then, how do they keep their atmosphere?
Radiations.

So, an alternative is something semi-magical and immune to a Jeans collapse like Virga; or a sufficiently-advanced-technology airsphere; or better yet, an unlikely but, they tell me, physically feasible Smoke Ring. In such a setting, dragons could thrive, adapting to air-swimming in microgravity. A sort of gravity can be supplied by tidal forces (see the Smoke Ring integral trees).
Much more farfetched, a multiple planetary system (they ought to orbit around a black hole, and the black hole around a distant, huge star to have at least some hope of short-term stability), a hybrid between a Klemperer rosette, Rocheworld and the twin system of Land and Overland in Bob Shaw's The Wooden Spaceships (an eagle had problems flying there). A Klemperer lagrangian rhombus would also work. In both cases, however, the "planets" are continuously aerobraking each other, which would lead to them all imploding against the primary or each other in very short time. Maybe if the "air corridor" between them was very small, as in The Wooden Spaceships, the braking effect could be tolerable. In both cases, also, you'd need to have the planets not rotating in respect to one another - a multiple tidal lock - or they'd dissipate their energy in short order.

did you make a flatulance joke? :D
